# How do I display this data in my columns?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with VueJS. I have a set of a lot of data. I want it to appear in my columns by order. How do I insert the code properly? Thanks for help.

```
[
  {
    "sort": 0,
    "title": "My title",
    "description": "My description"
  },
  {
    "sort": 1,
    "title": "My Title1",
    "description": "My description"
  },
  {
    "sort": 2,
    "title": "My title2",
    "description": "My description"
  },
]
```

I want it to go in here by order

```
<div class="row pt-md-5 mt-md-5 mb-5 p-4">
  <div class="col-xl-6 mx-auto">
    <div class="card p-3">
      <h3>Want the title here</h3>
      <p>Description here </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6 mx-auto">
    <div class="card p-3">
      <h3>Want the title here</h3>
      <p>Description here </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I go by the guide I get error on my website.


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    title: 'Hi',
    description: ' Here'
  }
})

> 25 | var app = new Vue({
     |               ^
  26 |   el: '#app',
  27 |   data: {
  28 |     title: 'Hi',

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Vue you can use the `v-for` directive to iterate over your objects and display them how you want:

```
  <div 
    v-for="(object, index) in array" 
    :key="index" 
    class="col-xl-6 mx-auto"
  >
    <div class="card p-3">
      <h3>{{ object.title }}</h3>
      <p>{{ object.description }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In the v-for, `object` can be named however you like, `array` *has* to be the name of your array, `index` is just the index of each object within that array, then, inside the `v-for`, you can access each objects properties using templates, i.e. `{{ object.title }}`.